# $\sin(at)$ Infinitely many values of $a$ despite infinitely many preconditions of $f(x)=\sin(at)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

A question popped into my head while doing some eigenfunction problems which is quite new to me.

Let's say we have a function $$f(t) = \sin(a \cdot t)$$ and let's say I have $n+1$ preconditions:

$$\begin{align*}
f(0) &= 0\\
f(t_1) &= u_1\\
f(t_2) &= u_2\\
&\vdots\\
f(t_n) &= u_n
\end{align*}$$

Where all the $t_i$ are distinct and all the $u_i$'s are bounded $-1\leq u_i\leq 1$

My instincts tells me there are always infinitely many values of $a$ that generate functions $f(t)$ that fulfil all the preconditions. Is this true?

How about as the number of preconditions $n$ approaches infinity? Are there still infinitely many values of $a$.

I have a feeling that this is true as we can make $a$ arbitrarily small and get so much precision such that no matter how crazy the preconditions are, it's still possible to find infinitely many $a$'s to do fulfil all of them.

Or is there a simple counterexample that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: there is no solution for

$$f(0)=f(1)=f( \sqrt{2} )=0$$

Indeed $\sin (at)$ is a periodic function. $$f(0)=f(1)=0$$ means that the period is rational, while $$f(0)=f(\sqrt{2})=0$$ means that the period is irrational.

Comment: Great counterexample, when looking at $f(1)=0$ I get the feeling that there are many values of $a$ between 0-1 that fulfil the condition. but thinking about it instantly makes it clear that $a=k\pi$ for integer k and that instantly kills so many possibilities. Thanks a lot, really cleared it for me.